# Lim sup and lim inf definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

$a_{n}=(-1)^n$ if n is even,$ a_{n}=\sqrt{n}$ if n is odd

infimum is 1

supremum is ∞ (if we allow ∞ as supremum. If we don't allow then we say supremum does not exist) because √n increases to infinity

for any m, the set an where n>=m has infimum 1 and supremum ∞, so the  limit inferior is 1 and limit superior is ∞

Is it right to my procedure?

Is there a way to make the result more formal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n = 1.$$
The $\liminf$ is the value of the smallest limit point of the sequence.  You have
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n = +\infty.$$ since a subsequence of the $a_n$ increases without bound.

Comment: Hello, Do you hear there would be a more formal way of doing it?

Comment: $\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n = \sup_{ N} \inf_{n \ge N} a_n$.  Since $a_n = 1$ infinitely often, $\inf_{n\ge N} a_n = 1$ for all $n$.  You can deal similarly to see how the $\limsup$ works.  BTW, the result I cite is widely known. If you are studying $\limsup$ and $\limsup$, see if you can prove it.

Comment: I can't believe I never realized that the lim inf is the least cluster point of a sequence! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I first saw this result in the book of Saxena and Shah.